# get all objects of json field from other app

Tags: python, django

I have a model class with json field:

```
class Collection(models.Model, AdminImageable):
    units = JSONField(verbose_name='element collection')
```

I'm trying get all objects of this field in other app with such code in my views.py

```
qwe = Collection.objects.filter(pagecollection__page_id=sluglist[0]).order_by('units') l = []
for col in qwe:
    l.append(
        apps.get_model(col.units['namespace'], col.units['model'], require_ready=True)
        )
```

But, I have a error --  list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Have you checked if `col.units` is a list?

Comment: what do you men???

Comment: Well, that's the only item in your code you appear to be applying a non-numeric `[]` to, so `print(col.units)` before you try the `l.append(...)` and see what it is... it's probably a list so the `col.units['namespace']`... is failing... It's a fairly simple debug step which you can then work out how to wish to proceed

Comment: i checked it - it's a list

Comment: Well, there you go then... that's what the error is telling... how you fix that is dependent on what you're trying to do which no-one else apart from you knows...

Comment: i want to get objects from units field